# Marking one value for hundred entries from a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file like below

```
apple lime apple lime apple lime jackfruit papaya apple banana carrot jackfruit papaya banana
apple lime apple lime apple lime jackfruit papaya apple banana carrot jackfruit papaya banana
apple lime apple lime apple lime jackfruit papaya apple banana carrot jackfruit papaya banana
```

Now i wanted to grep only apple, lime and banana from the file.

I used grep to find it

> grep 'apple|lime|banana' fruits.txt

Now this returns me all the entries, rather i would need it printed only once.

The output should be like

```
apple
lime
banana
```

Tried sort uniq and all didn't help much.

Comment: Since you said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721578/marking-one-value-for-hundred-entries-from-a-file/63725420#comment112686235_63722853) that your words can contain regexp metacharacters (e.g. `.` in `jack.fruit`) you should include a test case for that in your sample input/output (e.g. `jackOfruit`) so we and you can distinguish solutions that use regexps and so cannot work (i.e. anything with grep or sed) from solutions that can work (e.g. awk with a hash lookup or string comparison). You should also include `pineapple` in your sample to make sure `apple` doesnt match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `grep -o | sort -u` may work for you but if input is huge then it may not be very efficient.

This `gnu-awk` may work better for you:

```
awk -v s='apple lime banana' -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'BEGIN {
   split(s, a)
   for (i in a)
      wrds[a[i]]
}
$0 in wrds {
   print
   delete wrds[$0]
   if (length(wrds) == 0)
      exit

}' file
```

```
apple
lime
banana
```

Just for academic interest here is `grep + sort` command:

```
grep -owE 'apple|lime|banana' file | sort -u
```

Comment: If you do a `grep -oEw`, you don't need to explicitly match for word bounderies, which IMO makes the command a bit easier to read.

Comment: If the output is sorted `b` will always come before `l`.

Comment: In awk command, output is not sorted and that wasn't mentioned in requirements also.

Comment: The grep -owE doesn't really help much if i add another value like grape to it `grep -owE 'apple|lime|banana|grape' file | sort -u` the output returns that as well.

Comment: Adding up an mutating question, in my actual requirement the search values also contain symbols like hyphen and dots in it example "jack-fruit" and "jack.fruit" in that case this isn't working. What change is needed to manage this?

Comment: @Nishanth: awk solution doesn't depend on any regex so that should work for `jack-fruit` or `jack-fruit`

Comment: @Nishanth, in case you are expecting that you want to mention in awk variable like `-v s="jack-fruit"` and you want to match it to `jack.fruit` then its like totally different from your actual OP. Answers are always given as per shown samples only, if you change your samples now then answers will also have to be changed a lot I believe, so IMHO its a kind request to open a new question with your efforts, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v s1="apple lime banana" -v RS='[[:space:]]+'  '
BEGIN{
  num=split(s1,arr," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    wordArr[arr[i]]
  }
}
($0 in wordArr) && !count[$0]++
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v s1="apple lime banana" -v RS='[[:space:]]+'  '     ##Starting awk program from here, creating variable s1 which has all words which you want to match and get unique values. Then setting record separator as space here.
BEGIN{                                                    ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  num=split(s1,arr," ")                                   ##Splitting s1 into array arr with field separator as a space.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                                    ##Running for loop from i=1 to value of num here.
    wordArr[arr[i]]                                       ##Creating wordArr which has index of value of arr with index i here.
  }
}
($0 in wordArr) && !count[$0]++                           ##Checking condition if current line is present in wordArr and its NOT present in count then print the current line.
' Input_file                                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Adding up an mutating question, in my actual requirement the search values also contain symbols like hyphen and dots in it example "jack-fruit" and "jack.fruit" in that case this isn't working. What change is needed to manage this?

Comment: @Nishanth none. Like the other awk scripts posted so far, the script in this answer is doing a hash lookup of literal strings, it will work no matter which characters you have in your search values or input. If you're testing something and not getting the output you expect, either you copy/pasted the script wrong or you're doing something else that's not described in your question but I can't imagine what that would be. Actually one caveat- if your search values can contain escape sequences then use `ENVIRON[]` rather than `-v` to pass them into your awk script or escape them or hard-code them

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(((apple|banana|lime) ?)|\<\w+\> ?)/\2/g; # keep only the required words
        H;                                          # copy remains to hold space
        $!d;                                        # delete all lines except last
        x;                                          # last line swap to hold space
        s/\n/ /g;                                   # separate words by spaces
        :a;s/(( \w+).*)\2/\1/;ta;                   # remove duplicate words
        s/.//;                                      # remove leading space
        s/ /\n/g' file                              # separate words by new lines
```

Comment: This sed actually worked but it created huge amount of empty spaces when i redirect it to an variable.

Comment: @Nishanth  If the above solution works for data provided perhaps the data you are now using does not conform to the original data.

Comment: @Nishanth if you think that worked then the input you're testing with isn't adequate because, just like all the other grep and sed solutions,  it's doing a regexp comparison with the target strings and so will produce false matches, e.g. it'd match `jack.fruit` to `jackOfruit`.

Answer (score 0):

Converting all of the spaces to newlines with `tr` and then piping to `sort -u` will produce a small list to compare. Since you say in a comment that your target strings can contain regexp metacharacters (e.g. the `.` in `jack.fruit`) you cannot use a pipe to `grep -Ex 'apple|lime|banana'` for the final comparison phase nor is there any other way to use `grep` or `sed` and mix `|`s with fixed strings so we have to use `awk` with a hash lookup for the literal strings comparison:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file | sort -u |
    awk 'BEGIN{split("apple lime banana",tmp); for (i in tmp) tgts[tmp[i]]} $0 in tgts'
apple
banana
lime
```